# Notes in Telerik ScatterLine chart

Tags: jquery, charts, kendo-ui, scatter-plot

I am having below where I am able to draw event lines in the chart using **fromRect**.

```
var draw = kendo.drawing;
      var geom = kendo.geometry;

      var gradient = new draw.LinearGradient({
        start: [ 0, 0 ], // Bottom left
        end: [ 0, 1 ],   // Top left
        stops: [{
          offset: 0,
          color: "#5789c4",
          opacity: 0.5
        }, {
          offset: 1,
          color: "#5789c4",
          opacity: 0.5
        }]
      });

$("#chart").kendoChart({
        series: [{
          type: "scatterLine",
          data: [[1, 1], [-100, -100]]
        }],
        xAxis: {
          name: "xAxis"
        },
        yAxis: {
          name: "yAxis"
        },
        render: function(e) {
            var chart = e.sender;
            var xAxis = chart.getAxis("xAxis");
            var yAxis = chart.getAxis("yAxis");
            var xSlot = xAxis.slot(-80, null);
          var xSlot1 = xAxis.slot(-100, null);
            var ySlot = yAxis.slot(null, null);

            var rect = new geom.Rect([
              // Origin X, Y
              xSlot.origin.x, null
            ], [
              // Width, height
              10,601//xSlot.width(), ySlot.height()
            ]);

          var rect1 = new geom.Rect([
              // Origin X, Y
              xSlot1.origin.x, null
            ], [
              // Width, height
              10,601//xSlot.width(), ySlot.height()
            ]);

            var path = draw.Path.fromRect(rect, {
              stroke: { color: "#5789c4", width: 2 },
              fill: gradient
            });

          var path1 = draw.Path.fromRect(rect1, {
              stroke: { color: "#5789c4", width: 2 },
              fill: gradient
            });

            chart.surface.draw(path);
          chart.surface.draw(path1);
        }
      });
```

But I want to name them event lines with some text in a rectangle on top of the each line. Which I am not able to achieve. 
Even if there is an option to display some text for that particular event line on hover that will works for me. Please let me know if there is a way to achieve atleast one of these.

Answer (score 0):

Just use kendo.drawing.Text. For instance adding this block of code after your `chart.surface.draw(path1);`

```
 var pos = new geom.Point(xSlot1.origin.x, 0);
 var text = new draw.Text("MyText", pos);
 chart.surface.draw(text);
```

Adds text around the top of the 1st rectangle.